# Exporting to excel with proper cell formatting on ag-grid

Tags: javascript, excel, ag-grid

When I export a table to excel using ag-grid's own `exportDataAsExcel()` the resulting excel contains dates as **General** data type instead of **Date**.

[[image: excel pic]]

I have used this:

```
exportDataAsExcel({
   processCellCallback: ({col, val}) => {( /*date value formatting here*/ )}
})
```

to format both `Date`, `string` with proper date formatting `(DD/MM/YYYY)` but I can't make excel properly recognize these cells as **Date** instead of **General**

This is reproducible with the excel export examples on their website: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-excel/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 17):

I've used this code to apply value formatter in excell as well:

```
this.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsExcel({
  processCellCallback: (params) => {
    const colDef = params.column.getColDef()
    // try to reuse valueFormatter from the colDef
    if (colDef.valueFormatter) {
      const valueFormatterParams: ValueFormatterParams = {
        ...params,
        data: params.node.data,
        node: params.node!,
        colDef: params.column.getColDef()
      };
      return colDef.valueFormatter(valueFormatterParams);
    }
    return params.value;
  },
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to do three things:

1. When instantiating the Ag-Grid, you need to add (thanks to [another user's answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523883/1082063))

   ```
    let excelStyles = [
        {
            id: "ExcelDateTime",
            dataType: "dateTime",
            numberFormat: { format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss;;;" }
        },
        {
            id: "ExcelDate",
            dataType: "dateTime",
            numberFormat: { format: "yyyy-mm-dd;;;" }
        }
    ];
    ...
    <AgGridReact
        ... //such as   rowData={rowData}
        excelStyles={excelStyles}
        ...
    />;
   ```
2. For columns that are dates:

   ```
    colDef.cellClass = "ExcelDateTime";
   ```

   or

   ```
    colDef.cellClass = "ExcelDate";
   ```

   as appropriate, and
3. in your `processCellCallback`, format the date as an ISO date: `"yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss"`

Comment: I thought I had the answer to this one, but realized it was not consistently working. This particular answer took me a while to get figured out...but after reading the docs, and making it work...this is EXACTLY the answer. THANK YOU. https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview&preview and here: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/excel-export/  . This is the line that finally made it all click: "The silver column has a style with dataType=string. "  Thanks again

Comment: Thank you !  On agGrid's website, it says that dataType should be 'DateTime', rather than 'dateTime'.  Which is true ?   I have tried both, and I'm still getting my ISO-formatted dates being exported as data type General.   https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/excel-export-data-types/

Comment: @MikeGledhill: The code above is cut-and-paste from actual working coed.

Comment: I just noticed, if use the sample code on agGrid's own website, I get a load of warnings: "Unrecognized data type for excel export [excelDate.dataType=DateTime]"   So, YES, you absolutely do need to set the dataType to "dateTime" (with a lower-case D)

Comment: @DavidI.McIntosh  No - sorry, I was just confused, as agGrid's own code sample (in the link I quoted) is wrong.  I wasn't sure which version to trust.... and yes, your's was the correct version (with a lower-case "dateTime", rather than "DateTime").

Comment: @MikeGledhill: OK, NP, thanks for clarification.  It seems you corrected your comment to refer specifically to the "sample code on agGrids's own website" - I have deleted my other comment. But quick question: how did you edit your comment? I thought comments could only be edited within 5 minutes of posting? If you did not edit your comment (and it was always like this), then I must apologize for my comment as your previous comment, as it stands, is quite clear.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are in control of the server-side application, I have found it easier to do the export from the server-side for any non-trivial exports / formatting.

By doing it on the server, you are in complete control of the data and the production of the Excel file, and not dependent on the limits of Ag-Grid's implementation.

Comment: Not really an answer. this should be a comment at best