# In ag-grid Excel export, how to get a null datetime type to be empty cell instead of 1900.01.00

Tags: excel, datetime, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid and using its "export to excel" feature.  I am exporting a column which is a datetime type.  I am basically doing as I (very briefly) outlined in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523800/1082063) to another users question.  It works well, except for one glitch.

If an AG-grid cell value is null, i.e. the cell empty, I want the cell in the exported Excel workbook to also be empty.  However, when the "null" value is returned for a cell, ag-grid puts in a cell in the workbook with `<Data ss:Type="DateTime"></Data>`, which gets interpreted by Excel as 1900-01-00.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format the cells as `yyyy-mm-dd;;;` . A cell rendered blank by formatting exports a blank cell.

Comment: For anyone who checks out the link in my question above, I have edited my reply at that link to incorporate Jeeped's (correct) answer.  Thanks Jeeped.

Comment: No worries. Thanks to you for the kudos. btw, I'm pretty sure that's my first [tag:ag-grid] tag. I doubt if I'll be getting a gold on that tag anytime soon.